# SQL Converting a varchar to a clob within an SQL union

Tags: sql, oracle

Why does oracle not allow the following query

```
select to_clob(1) from dual
union
select wm_concat(sysdate) from dual;
```

`wm_concat` returns a clob. To make both queries in the union have the same type columns i convert the column in the first query to a clob but Oracle gives me an `[1]: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB` error even though both are returning a clob value.

Each of the queries work individually and both return a clob value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe `wm_concat` returns a `CLOB`.

This shows that the return is `Typ=1` which is a `VARCHAR2`

```
SQL> select dump(wm_concat(sysdate)) from dual;

DUMP(WM_CONCAT(SYSDATE))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=1 Len=9: 49,52,45,70,69,66,45,49,51
```

which you can also see if you create a view

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create view vw_wm_concat
  2  as
  3* select wm_concat(sysdate) col from dual
SQL> /

View created.

SQL> desc vw_wm_concat;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL                                                VARCHAR2(4000)
```

If you convert the `VARCHAR2` returned by `WM_CONCAT` into a `CLOB`, the next problem is that Oracle doesn't support doing a `DISTINCT` on a `CLOB` column which is required in order to do a `UNION`.  Assuming that you don't really need to remove duplicate rows, you can use a `UNION ALL` rather than a `UNION`.

Putting the two together, something like this

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1   select to_clob(1) from dual
  2   union all
  3* select to_clob(wm_concat(sysdate)) col from dual
SQL> /

TO_CLOB(1)
------------------------------------------------------------
1
14-FEB-13
```

will work

Comment: The reason i am using wm_concat() instead of listagg() is i was trying to avoid the 'ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long'. If wm_concat returns a varchar would i not have the same problem with wm_concat?

Thanks

Comment: @ziggy - I would expect that you would have a problem with `wm_concat` if the result was more than 4000 bytes, yes.

Comment: A bit offtopic, but if you insist on the clob, you can also use xmlconcat(...).getclobval(). But this way the aggregated string will be "XML formated".

Comment: @Ivan - That was actually the topic of another recent question asked by the same user-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864055/listagg-function-and-ora-01489-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long  I believe the concern with the XML approach was performance judging from the comments.