# How to tweak LISTAGG to support more than 4000 character in select query?

Tags: casting, oracle11g, collect

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

I have a table in the below format.

```
Name     Department
Johny    Dep1
Jacky    Dep2
Ramu     Dep1
```

I need an output in the below format.

```
Dep1 - Johny,Ramu
Dep2 - Jacky
```

I have tried the 'LISTAGG' function, but there is a hard limit of 4000 characters. Since my db table is huge, this cannot be used in the app. The other option is to use the

```
SELECT CAST(COLLECT(Name)
```

But my framework allows me to execute only select queries and no PL/SQL scripts.Hence i dont find any way to create a type using "CREATE TYPE" command which is required for the COLLECT command.

Is there any alternate way to achieve the above result using select query ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you cant create types (you can't just use sql*plus to create on as a one off?), but you're OK with COLLECT, then use a built-in array. There's several knocking around in the RDBMS. run this query:

```
select owner, type_name, coll_type, elem_type_name, upper_bound, length 
 from all_coll_types
 where elem_type_name = 'VARCHAR2';
```

e.g. on my db, I can use `sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY` which is a varray of considerable size.

```
select department, 
       cast(collect(name) as sys.DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY) 
  from emp 
 group by department;
```

Comment: Thanks Dazzal. The DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY is working in my db as well. I have found another way by using XMLAGG. Plz let me know which one is the best to use considering my emp table contains more than 20000 rows.

Comment: @AnuChandran test both to see which is better for you. the XML approach like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864055/listagg-function-and-ora-01489-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long)  will have some overhead though.

Answer (score 8):

You should add GetClobVal and also need to rtrim as it will return delimiter in the end of the results.

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,colname,',').EXTRACT('//text()') 
  ORDER BY colname).GetClobVal(),',') from tablename;
```

Comment: you have to unescape XML as well dbms_xmlgen.convert

Answer (score 5):

A derivative of @anuu_online but handle unescaping the XML in the result.

```
dbms_xmlgen.convert(xmlagg(xmlelement(E, name||',')).extract('//text()').getclobval(),1)
```

Answer (score 4):

For IBM DB2, Casting the result to a varchar(10000) will give more than 4000.

```
select column1, listagg(CAST(column2 AS VARCHAR(10000)), x'0A') AS "Concat column"...
```

Comment: Or go up to 32700 if 10000 is small for you.

Answer (score 3):

I end up in another approach using the XMLAGG function which doesn't have the hard limit of 4000.

```
select department,
XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,name||',')).EXTRACT('//text()')  
from emp 
group by department;
```

Comment: Useful, but note that the result may contain entity escapes.

Comment: I'm suspect to any function that blatantly brandishes the word LAG in its naming schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT department
     , REGEXP_REPLACE(XMLCAST(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(x, name, ',')) AS CLOB), ',$')
  FROM emp 
 GROUP BY department
```

it will return CLOB that has no size limit, handles correctly XML entity escapes and separators.

Instead of `REGEXP_REPLACE(..., ',$'))` you can use `RTRIM(..., ',')`, which should be faster, but will remove all separators from the end of the result (including those that can appear in `name` at the end, or previous ones if last `name`s are empty).