# ORACLE xmlagg limitations

Tags: oracle, xml-parsing

I have a table which has multiple lines of text that need to be merged into 1 line. I need to support strings longer than 4000 characters, so listagg is not an option.

I have done the following after much searching:

```
select mdesc.DEFINITION_ID,
        xmlagg(xmlelement(E,mdesc.record_desc||' ')).EXTRACT('//text()')
        FROM METRIC_DESC mdesc
        GROUP BY DEFINITION_ID
```

but my results are returned with certain characters escaped.

This SO thread has some suggestions

[How to tweak LISTAGG to support more than 4000 character in select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677446/how-to-tweak-listagg-to-support-more-than-4000-character-in-select-query)

but I cannot convert to CLOB for my purposes.

Any idea how I can get the results of the query in a usable format? (i.e. not CLOB and not escaped?)

Comment: Can you create your own aggregate function?  Or are you trying to do this in a single SQL statement?  I'm a bit confused by your comment that you're trying to support strings longer than 4000 bytes without using a `CLOB`.  In SQL, a `VARCHAR2` is limited to 4000 bytes (unless you happen to be using 12.1 and have enabled 32000 byte `VARCHAR2` values).  Anything longer than that would necessarily have to be some sort of `LOB`.

Comment: Some how the column being returned by xmlagg() function can support longer than 4000 characters, but it has escape characters. So I'm currently able to get this non-clob 4000+ character column, but it's has escape characters. I'm trying to do this in a single statement if possible.

Comment: `xmlagg` should be returning an XMLType object.  Under the covers, that is a `clob` in this case.  If, somehow, an `XMLType` is OK but a `clob` is not, can you create your own type that contains a `clob` and create your own aggregate function that returns an instance of this new type?  That seems like an unlikely setup but I don't understand why you're disallowing `clob` but allowing `XMLType`.

Comment: For some reason Crystal Reports will not display Clobs. the sole purpose of this query is for a Crystal Report. I might just truncate at around 4000 characters, what I need doesn't seem possible without a custom type and that isn't an option.

Comment: The answer I received to my question may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683423/is-oracles-extract-function-breaking-the-noentityescaping-in-the-xmlelement

Answer (score 1):

To convery  the XMLType object to a CLOB, You will need to add a `getClobVal()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `rtrim` function:

```
SELECT mdesc.definition_id, 
       Rtrim(Xmlagg(Xmlelement(e, mdesc.record_desc 
                                  || ' ')).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') 
FROM   metric_desc mdesc 
GROUP  BY definition_id ;
```