# Oracle Convert table rows to list

Tags: oracle

I have a table A with single column

```
 **TableA**
  Row1
  Row2
  Row3
  .....
```

I have to convert the table rows into a list and store them in variables. So that they are stored as

```
Row1,Row2,Row3,....,Rown
```

I used the listagg () function to achieve the solution.

```
DECLARE
tbl_list CLOB; 

BEGIN

SELECT  listagg (''''||Column_name||'''',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Column_name) INTO TBL_LIST FROM TableA;  
END;
```

This works fine if the TableA has few rows. But if the table has lots of rows I get the following error

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

Is this due to the storage limit of variable TBL_LIST? Can anyone explain me what is wrong. And is there an alternate for lisagg(), to achieve the result, I want?

Comment: Whay type is Column_name?Why do you have  to convert the table rows into a list ?

Comment: Might wanna look at this [String Aggregation Techniques](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques) if u wanna go for other techniques

Comment: column_name is varchar2, i need the rows to be ordered as a list like (row1,row2,....), because i am passing the variable tbl_list to another process which takes input in the form of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listagg` function is limited to 4000 characters, if it exceeds 4000 character yo may get an error `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`

You can use `XMLAGG` which is not limited to 4000 char.

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,''''||Column_name||'''',',').EXTRACT('//text()') 
    ORDER BY Column_name).GetClobVal(),',') 
from TableA;
```

you can refer this question: [How to tweak LISTAGG to support more than 4000 character in select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677446/how-to-tweak-listagg-to-support-more-than-4000-character-in-select-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the result of aggregation to be more than 4000 bytes? If so, you could potentially create a user-defined aggregate function that returns a CLOB rather than a VARCHAR2. If you don't expect the result to exceed 4000 bytes there is probably something wrong with the way you've specified the aggregate.

Please refer to the "https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques" for user defined aggregation.

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be that function is returning results more than 4000 bytes. Because the it works fine if the table has less number of rows.