# How to solve PLSQL ORA-06502

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions, ora-06502

I have a small function which uses a dynamic sql. I also need the dynamic sql, because I get the Viewname and the Where_clause during the runtime of my stored procedure.

```
create or replace FUNCTION Costs_MK(VIEWNAME     IN VARCHAR2,
                                    WHERE_Clause IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_Costs VARCHAR2(3000);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Select Listagg(Costs, ' || '''' || ';' || '''' || ' )
                     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Costs)
                       from (select distinct (Costs)
                       from ' || Viewname || ' where ' || where_Clause || ')'
  INTO v_Costs;

  dbms_output.put_line(length(v_Costs));

  RETURN v_Costs;
END Costs_MK;
```

Output:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: in Line 9
1600
```

The length is 1600 of the variable v_Costs and I already set the length to 3000. However I am getting this error everytime and I dont know what I can do, to solve this one.

Line 9 is:

```
Line 8: BEGIN
Line 9:
Line 10:   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
```

Anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
  VIEWNAME VARCHAR2(200);
  WHERE_Clause VARCHAR2(200);
  v_Return VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  VIEWNAME := 'Orders';
  WHERE_BEDINGUNG := 'Orders.key like ' || '''' || '  B01  230/01/123456%' || '''';

  v_Return := Costs_MK(
    VIEWNAME => VIEWNAME,
    WHERE_Clause => WHERE_Clause
  );

  /* Legacy output:
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v_Return = ' || v_Return);
   */
  :v_Return := v_Return;

  --rollback;
END;
```

And now I found the error. Because `v_Return VARCHAR2(200)` is only 200. If I raise it for example to 4000, I get the desired result. Ok, so I guess, I know how to solve this.

Comment: How are you calling this - from an anonymous block? If the error was coming from the function then it would include its name in the exception stack; you mention a procedure but its name doesn't appear either. Referring to a blank line would also be odd. But you would not see the `dbms_output` if the function was throwing the exception, so it seems to be the caller that is actually getting the exception.

Comment: Yes exactly I call it from an anonymous block. The Procedure calls this function, so I dont need to mention it in here. However, if I call it in the procedure, I get the same error message.

Comment: So please show the anonymous block (by editing the question). And the entire exception stack, if you've left anything off what you've already posted. You seem to be looking for the problem in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the output from

```
dbms_output.put_line(length(v_Costs));
```

... so your function is reaching that point, and therefore is not throwing an exception on line 9 (which is an empty line) or anywhere else before that output is generated.

Therefore it must be the caller that is getting the exception; either the procedure that calls the function, or the anonymous block that calls the procedure. But not the function itself.

Based on the exception stack shown it's coming from the anonymous block, since neither the procedure or function names are in that stack (though it's feasible you've left the procedure name out). Line 9 of the anonymous block must be assigning a value that is too long for a variable, but it's nothing to do with the function, unless you're appending the returned number to a string and it is that which is then too long.

Your anonymous block is doing this:

```
DECLARE
  ...
  v_Return VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  ...
  v_Return := Costs_MK(
    VIEWNAME => VIEWNAME,
    WHERE_Clause => WHERE_Clause
  );
```

So on line 9 you're trying to assign what you know is a 1600-character value to a variable you've declared as 200 characters; hence the error. Change the declaration of `v_Return` to match the function variable's size (or make them both 4000 to allow some more overhead).

Answer (score 0):

Try extending `v_Costs` out to 4000.  If you still receive the error, then the problem is that the string generated by LISTAGG is over 4000 (the maximum length of a VARCHAR2).

If that is the issue, you'll need to use XMLAGG or one of the solutions supplied in this question: [How to tweak LISTAGG to support more than 4000 character in select query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15677446/477563)

Comment: I extended v_Costs to 4000 and still get the same error. The Length shows me only 1600, thats what confuses me. From the programming logic: Does the query first Listagg and then Distinct the values? This would make sense.

Comment: Do me a favor, what does this query return? `SELECT SUM(LENGTH(costs) + 3*COUNT(*)) AS exp_length FROM (SELECT DISTINCT costs FROM viewname WHERE where_clause)`  (Manually substitute `viewname` and `where_clause` as appropriate)

Comment: @triplus - you could have a 1600 character string that is more than 4000 bytes, if you have a multibyte character set. I don't think that is what's happening, but it's possible.

Comment: I edited my question. Now I found the error. Calling it from an anonymous block causes the error, because the Return Value is only 200 Chars long.