# CHECKSUM_AGG Equivalent in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query with

```
STANDARD_HASH(Column1|Column2|ColumnN, 'MD5') AS HashValue
```

for each row in a table.

Is it possible to GROUP by ColumnX and produce a Aggregate of the hash values?

I've tried LISTAGG but unfortunately that results in too large a concatenation to hash without error (it's possible I'm not applying this correctly though).

PSEUDO ORACLE presentation of what I'd like to achieve:

```
SELECT ColumnX, UNKNOWN_AGGREGATE_FUNC(STANDARD_HASH(Column1|Column2|ColumnN, 'MD5'))
FROM TableY
GROUP BY ColumnX
```

Essentially my reasoning for this, is ideally I'd like to batch up, by ColumnX,the hash values so that I can transport the batch results over the wire for comparison with an external system and therefore not necessarily have to transport every row in the event the batches match.

Comment: Thanks MrEdmundo.  I wondered if this answer to a similar question would meet your need?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677446/how-to-tweak-listagg-to-support-more-than-4000-character-in-select-query#answer-15680555

Answer (score 2):

Convert the hashes into numbers, sum the hashes per batch, and then compare the sums.

### Sample Schema

```
--drop table tableY;
create table tableY(columnX number, column1 number, column2 number, columnN number);

insert into tableY values(1, 1,1,1);
insert into tableY values(1, 2,2,2);

insert into tableY values(2, 1,1,1);
insert into tableY values(2, 2,2,2);

insert into tableY values(3, 1,1,1);
```

### Compare SQL

The conversion gets a bit ugly.  One of the main limitations is numeric precision, which is the reason for the `SUBSTR(..., 1, 15)`.

Substringing and summing hashes like this probably loses some important cryptographic properties but this should be good enough for comparisons.

```
select
    columnX,
    trim(
        upper(
            to_char(hash_sum, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
        )
    ) hash_sum
from
(
    select columnX, 
        sum(
            to_number(
                substr(
                    standard_hash(column1||column2||columnN, 'MD5')
                    , 1, 15
                )
                , 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            )
        ) hash_sum
    from tableY
    group by columnX
);

COLUMNX   HASH_SUM
-------   --------
1         1264B85078436A7F
2         1264B85078436A7F
3         698D51A19D8A121
```

Comment: Happy with loss of cryptographic properties, looking to use this for relatively large scale generic comparison of remote tables, will give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 20c supports [CHECKSUM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/checksum.html#GUID-3F55C5DF-F23A-4B2F-BC6F-E03B34B78BA8) analytical/aggregate function:

> Use CHECKSUM to detect changes in a table. The order of the rows in the table does not affect the result.
>
> You can use CHECKSUM with DISTINCT, as part of a GROUP BY query, as a window function, or an analytical function.

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT ColumnX, CHECKSUM(STANDARD_HASH(Column1|Column2|ColumnN, 'MD5'))
FROM TableY
GROUP BY ColumnX;
```

Comment: This looks like a much nicer solution than my answer, for people on 20c+.

Comment: @JonHeller Yes, with each version we are getting more and more goodies, that solve old cases.