# ERROR at line 191: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select TO_CLOB(a)|| TO_CLOB(b)|| TO_CLOB(c) || TO_CLOB(d) 
  from table1
```

Above query is not spooling the data properly into text file.

whereas,

```
Select a||b||c||d 
  from table1.
```

is ending to

> ERROR at line 191: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long.

Please help !!!

Comment: Some avail. are tips at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864055/listagg-function-and-ora-01489-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long

Answer (score 1):

VARCHAR2 are limited to 4000 bytes. If you get this error

> ERROR at line 191: ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too
>   long.

Then it is pretty clear that the concatenation exceed 4000 bytes.

Now what to do ?

Your first solution to use CLOB instead is correct.

```
select TO_CLOB(a)|| TO_CLOB(b)|| TO_CLOB(c) || TO_CLOB(d)
```

It seems like your real problem is saving to file

> Above query is not spooling the data properly into text file.

While you did not post how to save the resulting clob to a file, I believe you are not doing it correctly. If you try to save to file the same way as you were doing it with VARCHAR2, you are doing it wrong.

You need to first use `dbms_lob.read` to read the clob from database, then use `utl_file.put_raw` to write to file.

```
DECLARE
    position NUMBER := 1;
    byte_length NUMBER := 32760;
    length NUMBER;
    vblob BLOB;
    rawlob RAW(32760);
    temp NUMBER;
    output utl_file.file_type;
BEGIN
    -- Last parameter is maximum number of bytes returned.
    -- wb stands for write byte mode
    output := utl_file.fopen('DIR', 'filename', 'wb', 32760);

    position := 1;
    select dbms_lob.getlength(yourLob)
    into len
    from somewhere
    where something;

    temp := length;

    select yourLob
    into vlob
    from somewhere
    where something;

    IF len < 32760 THEN
        utl_file.put_raw(output, vblob);
        -- Don't forget to flush
        utl_file.fflush(output);
    ELSE -- write part by part
        WHILE position < len AND byte_length > 0
        LOOP
           dbms_lob.read(vblob, byte_length, position, rawlob);

           utl_file.put_raw(output,rawlob);

           -- You must admit, you would have forgot to flush.
           utl_file.fflush(output); 

           position := position + byte_length;

           -- set the end position if less than 32000 bytes
           temp := temp - bytelen;
           IF temp < 32760 THEN
               byte_length := temp;
           END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about increasing the value for LONG? You might have to increase the long variable to a higher value. Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2699121) for detailed description.

Example:

```
 SET LONG 100000;
 SPOOL test_clob.txt
 SELECT to_clob(lpad('A',4000,'A'))
       ||'B'
       ||to_clob(lpad('C',4000,'C'))
       ||'D'
       ||to_clob(lpad('E',4000,'E'))
       ||'F'
  FROM dual;
 SPOOL OFF;
```

Your second query returns error because,
The concat(||) operator in the query is trying to return varchar2, which has limit of 4000 characters and getting exceeded.

Comment: Is SET LONG a system wide parameter or does it only work for the query that is being launched?

Comment: @DavideInglima From the documentation : *"The SET statement assigns values to different types of variables that affect the operation of the server or your client."*

Answer (score -1):

SQL*Plus hardcode linesize 81 when displaying CLOB, there seems no way around it.  Therefore if you want to generate a csv file to be loaded to other databases,  you will have a problem of parsing these extra newlines.

The ultimate solution is to use PL/SQL.  For example, to genarate a comma delimited csv file from table "xyz", use the following code:

```
set lin 32766 
set serveroutput on size unlimited

DECLARE
     TYPE arraytable IS TABLE OF xyz%ROWTYPE;
     myarray  arraytable;
     CURSOR  c IS
     select * from  xyz ;
BEGIN
    OPEN c;
    LOOP
        FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO myarray  LIMIT 10000; 
        FOR i IN 1 .. myarray.COUNT
           LOOP
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
                   myarray(i).col1||','||
                   myarray(i).col2||','||
                   myarray(i).col3||','||
                   myarray(i).col4;
        END LOOP;
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

A bonus of this approach is that this even works with LONG datatype!

Comment: You are still concatenating VARCHAR > 4000 bytes.

Comment: @ Jean-Francois Savard,    No.  The output from PL/SQL is no longer VARCHAR.  Therefore it will not be restricted by the 4000 size limitation.

Answer (score -1):

Try xmlagg function. That worked well for me when I encountered a similar issue.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm